# Wann konvertieren/formatieren/transcodieren?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Was genau ist der Unterschied zwischen konvertieren, transcodieren und formatieren?
Wann wendet man genau was an?
Vielen Dank für jegliche Hilfe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das hat eigentlich nicht viel mit deutscher Sprache zu tun, sondern eher mit EDV-Fachwissen. Naja, nichtdestoumso....

> "Formatieren

... hat zwei mögliche Bedeutungen: erstens, das Vorbereiten eines Datenträgers zum Speichern von Daten. (zB Festplatten werden formatiert). Zweitens bedeutet es das Auszeichnen von Text(-Teilen): welcher Font wird verwendet, in welcher Größe, Zeilen-, Spalten- und Seitenumbruch, Durchschuß, Unterschneidung, das Vermeiden von Hurenkindern und dergleichen mehr.

> transkodieren ...

wird auch mit dem grauenhaften "Umschlüsseln" bezeichnet und beschreibt das Wechseln von Datenbankschlüsseln oder des Encodings (Wechseln der zugrundeliegenden Zeichentabelle). Für den Wechsel kryptographischer Schlüssel ist das Wort ungebräuchlich.

> konvertieren ...

... hat mehr Bedeutungen, als ich sie hier aufzählen könnte und bedeutet allgemein "Wechsel zu etwas anderem". Unter "konvertieren" versteht man unter anderem den Wechsel des Glaubensbekenntnisses, aber auch - ich vermute mal, es geht um EDV - den Wechsel eines Aufzeichnungsformats. zB wird ein Dokument von einem Tabellenkalkulationsformat in ein Datenbankformat *konvertiert*.

Das Substantiv lautet übrigens beim Wechsel des Aberglaubens "Konversion", hingegen beim Wechsel des Dokumentenformats "Konvertierung".

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Antwort. Man merkt du hast echt was drauf. Habe ich richtig verstanden, transkodieren benutzt man bei der Umwandlung einer Datei welcher einen Codec besitzt (mp4, mp3 …). Und konvertieren wenn man eine Datei umwandelt die keinen Codec besitzt wie jpeg, docx?

Comment: @Lano: vielen Dank für das Lob, auch wenn ich nicht glaube, es zu verdienen. Ich habe mit Multimedia wenig zu tun, und es gibt bei dem Sprachgebrauch auch wenige regelrechte Vorschriften. Ich würde hier wohl in beiden Fällen "konvertieren" sagen.

Comment: @Lano: Transkodieren benötigt üblicherweise eine gewisse Prozessorleistung zur "umrechung" und wird typischerweise bei Video- und Audio- Files verwendet. Das allgemeinere konvertieren findet bei "einfacheren" Umwandlungen, typischerweise Bilddaten, Text- Formaten o.ä. Anwendung, könnte aber auch bei Audio / Video verwendet werden

Comment: @Tode Vielen Dank. Ich weiß deine Antwort wirklich zu schätzen. Ich verstehe einfach mal was konvertieren betrifft, die allgemeine Umwandlung, das heißt alles was umgewandelt wird kann man konvertieren nennen. Wenn man es spezifisch haben möchte, kann man statt konvertieren auch transkodieren sagen, das betrifft jedoch nur digitale Audio-/Videodateien + Zeichencodierung und keine Bilddateien oder ähnliches, dann nutz ich konvertieren. So wie ich es verstanden habe

Comment: @bakunin mir ist erst vor wenigen Tagen "umschlüsseln" im Sinne des Wechsels der Zeichentabelle erstmals im Berufsalltag begegnet, und ich schließe mich deinem ästhetischen Urteil dazu voll und ganz an ;-) Ich bin zwar nicht ganz sicher woran es liegt, aber in meinen aktiven Wortschatz kommt das nicht...

Comment: @Lano So hart kann man das für Multimedia nicht sagen. Z.B. ist grob gesagt ein JPEG-Bild technisch das gleiche wie ein einzelnes Bild eines der gängigen Videoformate. Heißt: Ein Foto oder ein Video von einem Format ins andere umzuwandeln ist die gleiche Art von Prozess. Wie »konvertieren« und »transkodieren« verwendet wird, ist eher Konvention abhängig vom Fachgebiet. »Transkodieren« für Text klingt z.B. für meine multimedia-geprägten Ohren seltsam. Für einen Unicode-Experten mag das ganz anders sein.

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transkodierung In Wikipedia wird nur von Audio/Video + Zeichencodierung gesprochen. Scheint so als wäre das Thema selber noch etwas unschlüssig.